# Unique content in each component in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Program description:** I'm making a simple timetable program with Vue.js. The page has a "calendar" (a table of 7 columns, where each column correspond to a specific date) and a button on the bottom of each calendar column. On clicking a button a modal should pop up with a specific date in its body-content. The date in the body-content of the modal should be the same as in date in the column title, where the button is placed. Dates can also be changed on click of a `forward` or `backward` button. When clicking `forward` all dates shift one day forward. In case of `backward` all dates shift one day backward.

**Approach to the program:** I have a parent component `App.vue` and a child component for the modal `modal.vue`. In the parent component as one of the attributes I have array `dateArr` which contains 7 different dates in the following format: `['9/11/21', '9/12/21', ..., '15/11/21']`. On `App.vue` mount `getDatesArray` method is being called which fills `dateArr` attribute with dates. On clicking `backward` and `forward` `currentOffset` is being changed and `getDatesArray` method is being triggered. The first row of the table consists of dates, therefore I create it with `v-for` and iterate over each `date` in `dateArr`. The body of the table consists of 3 rows in each column. The last row in each column contains a unique button and a modal. In the last row I want to bind each component to a specific date, so I yet again iterate over each `date` in `dateArr`. The modal component has a slot in it, where I put unique `date` from `dateArr`. On click of the button the visibility of the modal changes with `change` method.

**Problem:** Everything works well, however, whatever button I click, the content (`date`) of the modal component stays the same: `15/11/21`, which is the last element of the array. The purpose of the program is to have unique content (`date`) inside each modal component with the core attribute (`dateArr`) being dynamic. I've tried implementing different solutions to this problem, but none were of use. I will really appreciate any help!

**`App.vue`**:

```js
<template>
  <table class = 'dataFrame'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="item in dayArr" :key="item.id">
          {{item}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="index in [1,2,3]" :key="index">
        <td v-for="item_index in dayArr.length" :key="item_index">
          Dummy content
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="date in dayArr" :key="date.id">
          <button @click="change">+</button>
          <modal-component @changevisibility="change" v-if="modalToggled">
            <p>{{ date }}</p>
          </modal-component>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="buttonSection">
      <button @click="currentOffset --" class="back" v-show="currentOffset >= -7">forward</button>
      <button @click="currentOffset ++" class="forward" v-show="currentOffset <= 7">backward</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import basecard from './components/card.vue'
import navbarComponent from './components/menu.vue'
import modalComponent from './components/modal.vue'

export default {
  data() {
            return {
                currentOffset: 0,
                modalToggled : false,
                dayArr: []
            }
        },
  methods: {
      change() {
        this.modalToggled = !this.modalToggled
      },
      getDatesArray() {
          let date = new Date();
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + this.currentOffset);
          let dayArr = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {      
            let customDateArray = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }).formatToParts(date)   
            let dateParts = {}
            customDateArray.map(({type, value}) => {
              dateParts[type] = value
            })
            dayArr.push(`${dateParts.day}/${date.getMonth()+1}/${dateParts.year.slice(-2)}`)
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
          }
          this.dayArr = dayArr
      }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getDatesArray()
  },
  watch: {
    currentOffset () {
      this.getDatesArray()
    }
  },
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    modalComponent
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    display: flexbox;
    font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #2c3e50
  }

  .dataFrame {
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: #2c3e50;
  }

  .buttonSection {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  .back {
    float: left;
  }

  .forward {
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

**`modal.vue`**:

```js
<template>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <slot></slot>      
            <button @click="changeVisibilityFromComponent">
                    <span class="close">Close &times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'modalComponent',
    methods: {
        changeVisibilityFromComponent () {
            this.$emit('changevisibility')
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.modal {
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; 
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I thought about is to pass an index to change function, thus calculating some value independent of the v-for loop:

```
<td v-for="(date, index) in dayArr" :key="date.id">
  <!-- pass index to change method -->
  <button @click="change(index)" :id="index">+</button>
  <modal-component @changevisibility="change(index)" v-if="modalToggled">
    <!-- to slot pass the new variable -->
    <!-- remember to add it to data() with some init value like null -->
    <p>{{ currentDate }}</p>
  </modal-component>
</td>
```

...

```
methods: {
    change(index) {
      // set currentDate value each time change method is being run
      this.currentDate = this.dayArr[index];
      this.modalToggled = !this.modalToggled
    },
    ...
}
```

The reason for the issue you’ve experienced, is that v-for renders a list of items and sets the variables in a same way the code below does:

```
let x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = i;
}
console.log(x); // this will always console out x = 9
```

In contrary, event handling (like `@click`) makes a directive that listens to DOM events and runs a method each time the event is triggered. That’s at least how I understand it…